# Duplicating DIV elements in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm managing a website, and I know "just enough to be dangerous" about CSS. The site is `sakonnetpreservation(dot)org`.

I would like to duplicate the "membership" button in the header. That's `div.membership-cta`. We want to add a "donate" button that has the same appearance.

I would also like the option of adding another row of widgets: currently a row of 3 for educational programs, our annual meeting, and our most current newsletter. That's `div.home-ctas`.

I tried copy-pasting the div section with the rename of `donate-cta`, but it disrupts the entire script's formatting.

```
.donate-cta h3 a {
color:#00aabc;
background:#0b3a44;
padding:5px 25px 5px 35px;
font-size:28px; 
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
font-family: "Bebas Kai",sans-serif;

}
.donate-cta h3 a:hover, .donate-cta h3 a:active  {
color:#0b3a44;
background:#00aabc;
}
```

I did register copies of the widgets in the functions file, but it didn't create another row. Instead, it displaced the 3rd existing widget in the row.

I think I need to create a duplicate div, something like `home-ctas-row2`, but now I'm second, third, and fourth-guessing myself.

What I duplicated, just changing the name and ID:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Home - Current/Just-In-Time',
    'id' => 'home-our-mission',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-wrapper">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Home - Educational Programs & Events',
    'id' => 'home-little-compton-special',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-wrapper">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Home - Newsletter',
    'id' => 'home-membership',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-wrapper">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title"><h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
) );
```

How I duplicated the `home-ctas` div - which maybe I also need to do with the other relevant div classes so they aren't competing for the same space? (i.e. `.textwidget, .widget-wrapper`)

```
.home-ctas2 .col-300 .textwidget p .alignnone,.home-ctas .col-300 .textwidget p {margin:0;padding:0;} 
.home-ctas2 a .col-300 h3 { 
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0 10px 0;
    font-family: "Bebas Kai",sans-serif; font-size:25px;
}

.home-ctas2 .col-300 h3 a { 
    color:#fff; 
    font-family: "Bebas Kai",sans-serif; font-size:25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

.home-cta4 {background:#86a23d; } 

.home-cta5 { background:#5b9498; } 

.home-cta6 { background:#28606e; } 

.home-ctas2:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}

.home-ctas2 img { width:100%; object-fit: cover; max-height:209px; }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the rouge backtick (`\``) at the end of `color:#00aabc;\`` a typo in the question, or the actual CSS, because that doesn't belong there and could be breaking things.

Comment: Ugh, no it's being a newbie at StackOverflow. It wouldn't let me post at first because code wasn't offset properly, and I had to attempt multiple methods before it would let me post. That's just a leftover from that process. I'll edit to remove it now so it doesn't confuse folks.

Comment: This looks like it should have a few more tags than just CSS. What environment are you in? Is it Wordpress and is the WP functions.php file the one that you mention?

Comment: Yes, it is within Wordpress. The parent theme is Responsive. The original developer created a customized child theme. Being new to StackOverflow, the tags were a little overwhelming, but I added it based on your suggestion.

Comment: On your site I already see a button « donate » with the same appearance as « membership ». So is this problem solved?